# Access and modify Django DB without login in as superuser

Tags: python, django, web

I have a newbie question here. I'm currently working on a site where the user can add items to a model I created. The thing works fine if I'm logged in as super admin in the Django admin panel, but if I'm not, the CSRF verification doesn't work and I can't operate.

Is this a "Debug: True" thing? Once I'm ready to production and turn debug off, will it work without login? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe its permission issues? Can you share the error message as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't addint the {{csrf_token}} in the template. Adding it solved it